# Salesforce Test.loadData without inserting the records?

Tags: csv, unit-testing, salesforce, staticresource, test-data

So, we have a Test Data Factory that creates many test Lead records.  Some tests need inserted Leads with Ids, some do not.

I'm writing my Test Data Factory to reference a CSV file in Static Resources named 'testLeads'.
The problem is that `Test.loadData(lead.sObjectType, 'testLeads');` will insert the records before returning it.

What I have:

```
List<Lead> testLeads = Test.loadData(lead.sObjectType, 'testLeads');
Assert.isNotNull(testLeads[0].Id);
```

What I need:

```
List<Lead> testLeads = Test.loadData(lead.sObjectType, 'testLeads');
Assert.isNull(testLeads[0].Id);
insert testLeads;
Assert.isNotNull(testLeads[0].Id);
```